# jQuery.html( something ) detect when injection is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a nutshell I want a callback to fire after the html has been injected and the content of that html has rendered. Reason being I need to know the height of the new content right away. Something like this:

```
  $('div').html(tonsofstuff);
  console.log( $('div').height() ); //works in Firefox, but returns 0 in Chrome
  setTimeout(function(){
        console.log( $('div').height() ); //works everywhere, but takes too long
  },3000);
```

The issue is occasionally in some browsers (and always in chrome) $('div').height() fires before the new content has a height.

My fantasy:

```
  $('div').html(tonsofstuff, function(){
        console.log( $('div').height() );
  });

  or even

  $('div').html(tonsofstuff).load(function(){
        console.log( $('div').height() );
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
var height = $('div').html(tonsofstuff).height();
```

I never had any problems with waiting for it to render.

Comment: It may problems with asynchronous things like iframes that are reaching into the outer window to resize themself

Comment: Worked perfect for my purposes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If issue occurs in chrome I assume that content you are inserting contains come images. Chrome does not calculate dimentions of the images until they are completely loaded (DOM ready is not enough). So what can usualy fix the problem is executing your rendering on window.onload event. This way you make sure images loaded and `.height()` / `.width()` will work fine. Although I realize that it's not always possible because `window.onload` event is fired much after then `DOMContentLoaded`.

Another approach is to specify image dimentions explicitly via `width` and `height` attributes of the corresponding image tag. This can work if you know the image sizes. In this case it's not necessary to perform your logic on `window.onload`.

Comment: I tried this actually. If the user has already seen the page, the content is cached, and onload does not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If your "tonsofstuff" has images, the setTimeout attack is the wrong approach.  You need to know when *each of the images* are are loaded, then do your DOM height calculations.  And for that, well, you may have to introspect the html to load, find the images, and use a call to somethig like the [Image Preloader Plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Image-Preloader).  I'm not necessarily recommending it; it's fairly trivial to write your own (although there may be some gotchas with certain methods). I just know there are things like this out there that should work pretty well.

Comment: BTW, when I said images, I meant *image tags*.

Comment: If he is loading images, and they have a fixed height, he could add some css to keep the page from growing as they load.

Comment: There are images, but I use the height attribute to prevent another reflow. Chrome does read this, so waiting for images in the dom is not an issue.